# How to configure Jenkins to test a nodejs project with webdriverio

Tags: node.js, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I'm using a project based on Node.JS:

There is a part of package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "test-server-setup": "./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone install",
    "test-server-run": "./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone start",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "selenium-standalone": "^5.9.0",
    "wdio-chai-plugin": "0.0.2",
    "wdio-dot-reporter": "0.0.6",
    "wdio-json-reporter": "^0.1.0",
    "wdio-mocha-framework": "^0.5.4",
    "wdio-spec-reporter": "0.0.3",
    "webdriverio": "^4.4.0"
}
```

Instead of commands:

```
"test-server-setup": "./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone install",
"test-server-run": "./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone start",
```

I think to use the Jenkins-plugin [Selenium Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin)

Can I use `wdio` or I need to initialize the `browser` object something else?

http://localhost:4444/wd/hub has the error:

```
{
    status: 13,
    value: {
        message: "Session [(null externalkey)] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions. Active sessions are[]",
        class: "org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException",
        stackTrace: [
        {
            fileName: "ActiveTestSessions.java",
            className: "org.openqa.grid.internal.ActiveTestSessions",
            methodName: "getExistingSession",
            lineNumber: 110
        },
...
```